# Windows 8 Credential Provider Domain Users

Tags: c++, credential-providers, credui

I have been having issues trying to get domain users to authenticate with my custom credential provider. From the Microsoft sample there is a `_fIsLocalUser` variable which is checked in `CSampleCredential::GetSerialization`. This is normally true for most cases; however, if connected to a domain and with the `Other User` tile then I get `The parameter is incorrect`. It seems that even the suggested format of `<Domain>\<Username>` isn't accepted when the credential is Serialized. If possible I would also like to support `<Username>@<UPN>` as well.

I am not sure if this method is the problem however here is the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374802(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you help me in a similar problem? I have a credprov, but I don't see the sign-in options when I trying it with a domain user. It seems to me from your post that you achieved it.

Comment: Stuck with the same problem. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve your issue?

I just clicked the link you supplied with the answer and found a note to `pszUserName` parameter.

> For online identities, if the credential is a plaintext password, the
>   user name format is ProviderNameUserName. If the credential is a
>   SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_EX2 structure, the user name is an encoded
>   string that is the UserName parameter output of a function call to
>   SspiEncodeAuthIdentityAsStrings.

The function `SspiEncodeAuthIdentityAsStrings` has it's alter ego - [SspiEncodeStringsAsAuthIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/sspi/nf-sspi-sspiencodestringsasauthidentity) - have to look at it.